# python pipe gets output from wrong subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I have an app written in python 3.2 running in linux that makes heavy use of the subprocess module and theading.  One of the functions is to call a custom script to get the up/down status of various domain specific processes.  Since we have hundreds, the status uses multiple threads.  The application runs an xmlrpc server in "threading" mode to service incoming requests.

```
class AsyncXMLRPCServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn,SimpleXMLRPCServer) : pass

server = AsyncXMLRPCServer((LocalHost, 3200), requestHandler=RequestHandler, logRequests=False)
server.register_function( .... )
server.serve_forever()
```

Recently I ran into a problem where the output from one process was sent into TWO processes.  After much checking and logging, it seems somehow the subprocess.PIPE gets its wires crossed.  The problem always occurs on a pair of processes, and never the same pair.

Original code.  Each thread runs a copy of this

```
os.chdir(loc[1])
p = subprocess.Popen( cmd , stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = p.communicate()
out = out.decode('utf-8')
if err != None :
   err = err.decode('utf-8')

 logger.info('Output from %s WrapperScript.py', loc[1])
 logger.info(out)
 logger.info(err)
 .... followed by code to parse out and err to return results .....
```

When the results come back I see the text for ProcessA and ProcessB are identical, and the log files show the same thing.  something like so:
2014-06-02 13:31:47,454 INFO   : Output from /home/startup/ProcessOne WrapperScript.py
2014-06-02 13:31:47,455 INFO   : ProcessOne Running
2014-06-02 13:31:48,456 INFO   : Output from /home/startup/ProcTwo WrapperScript.py
2014-06-02 13:31:48,457 INFO   : ProcessOne Running

The log files are generated using the regular python logging module

```
logger  = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logfile, maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=5)
logger.setLevel(logging.WARN)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-7s: %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler( handler )
```

So I updated "wrapperScript" to write its output to local file system.  Both WrapperScript files (stored in separate folders)  wrote the correct data.  So that was not the problem.

Next I changed Popen to send stdout and stderr to a tempfile:

```
os.chdir(loc[1])
tmpErr = open(loc[1]+os.sep+'err.txt', 'w+b')
tmpOut = open(loc[1]+os.sep+'out.txt', 'w+b')
p = subprocess.Popen( cmd , stdout=tmpOut, stderr=tmpErr)
out,err = p.communicate()

tmpOut.seek(0)
tmpErr.seek(0)
out = tmpOut.read().decode('utf-8')
err = tmpErr.read().decode('utf-8')

logger.info('Output from %s WrapperScript.py', loc[1])
logger.info(out)
logger.info(err)
tmpOut.close()
tmpErr.close()
```

That gave me the same results - 2 random processes always shared the same output.
Changing from a temp file to a regular file in the same folder as my wrapper script had no effect.  but unlike the temp file I was able to see output after the threads completed.  The results were the same.  2 of the output files had the same contents.

How do I fix this?  or at least get closer where the problem is?

Comment: Where/how is your `logger` defined?

Comment: updated question with details on logger

Comment: I suspect this is related to mixing threads and `fork()`: http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them. Does the problem go away if you use the `close_fds=True` option when you call `Popen`?

Comment: re-trying with close_fds=True in Popen does not fix the problem